Connect speaker to Windows on 5.1 channel?
I have Sony HT-S20R 5.1 sound system. and my laptop is Clevo N957TP6
I have tried Analog audio port, digital audio port, realtek driver, Creative Sound Blaster. But I still get only 2.0 channel.
I want to be able to configure out channels on my computer. What should I do?

Based on the schematics I see only two channels for audio, page 98, pins 40, 41, 44, 45.
So you should add external audio card (5.1) to be able to use your soundsystem.

Is this what you are talking about?

@CodePanda, exactly. But you should not expect great sound quality.

I got this. I connected speaker to digital audio. Still get 2.0 channel.
